# How to use ArrayAdapter<String> inside as OnClickListener in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I want to fill my ListView when a button clicked but i have a problem with ArrayAdapter's constructor .

When i use this codes inside of "onCreate" method it works fine,I think the "this" keyword make this problems when i use ArrayAdapter inside of OnClickListener .

```
mybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTest);
myXMLListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.xmlListView);

View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
            your_array_list.add("foo");
            your_array_list.add("bar");

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,your_array_list);

            myXMLListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    };
    mybtn.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```

> Error:(62, 53) error: no suitable constructor found for
>   ArrayAdapter(,int,ArrayList)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List) is
>   not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not
>   applicable (actual argument  cannot be
>   converted to Context by method invocation conversion) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
>   (actual argument  cannot be converted to
>   Context by method invocation conversion) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable (actual
>   argument  cannot be converted to Context by
>   method invocation conversion) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable (actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate the `ArrayAdapter` as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityName.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,your_array_list);
```

The meaning of `this` is different where you are using it and hence there is a type mismatch in the parameters. use `ActivityName.this` instead of just `this` in the constructor, where `ActivityName` is the name of activity which contains that code.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global context initialize it inside the onCreate and then use it inside the ArrayAdapter

```
private Context context;

//Inside OnCreate
context = this;
```

Then you can use this context

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,your_array_list);
```